# Reverse geocoding in BASH - error using variable as coordinates

Tags: bash, reverse-geocoding

im trying to use variables instead of static coordinates in the code below, but without any succes.

What am i doing wrong here ?

```
stored_address=$(curl -s "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="'${coor1}'","'${coor2}'"&sensor=false" | grep -B 1 "route" | awk -F'"' '/short_name/ {print $4}')
```

My curl works if I use coordinates instead of the two variables "'${coor1}'" and "'${coor2}'", could someone please point out the error, thanks :)

working example with static coordinates:

```
stored_address=$(curl -s "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=56.433125,10.07003&sensor=false" | grep -B 1 "route" | awk -F'"' '/short_name/ {print $4}')
```

Answer (score 2):

you're using hard quoting, i.e. you wrap your variables in `'`. lose the single quotes and the variables will be expanded correctly:

```sh
stored_address=$(curl -s "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${coor1},${coor2}&sensor=false" | grep -B 1 "route" | awk -F'"' '/short_name/ {print $4}')
```

from the [bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your input, i've tried that allready, and that don't seem to work either

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" isn't a useful description. What *does* happen, and what did you *expect* to happen.

Comment: when using the static coordinates a string is stored in "stored_address", this variable is empty when using the variables, and im using the exact same coordinates as in the static example, which should give the same result

Comment: @BulletEyeDK, well, the issue than is in populating the coordinates variables, and since it's not included in the question, it is not possible to investigate further. i suggest you do some more investigation yourself, and post a new question when you recognise the real issue.

Comment: Ok, i will do that ;)